# Validate a string using pack('H*')

Tags: php

I'm working on an encrypted database... I have been using m_crypt functions.. I have sucessfully got my method of encryption/decryption.. But a problem lies with creating my OO class to serve this function.. I have the following:

```
class Encryption {
    public function __construct($Hex = null){
        if (isset($Hex)){
            if (ctype_xdigit($Hex)){
                echo "Is Hex";
            }
            if (preg_match('~^[01]+$~', $Hex)) {
                echo "Is Binary";
            }
        }
    }
}

$key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
$Class_OO = new Encryption($key);
```

The `echo`s are for testing purposes.. But I want to validate this as a valid hexidecimal/binary or the datatype this string is.

performing:

```
print_r($key);
```

Returns the following:

> ¼°K~:ØµGcï¼U«à)ýë®^A~/û*£

But what datatype is this? On the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php  The line is presented:

> convert a string into a key
>
> key is specified using hexadecimal

So my question is what datatype is this? I understand this is in the ASCII range, but that is as far as my knowledge goes.. Furthermore, a successful answer for this will also assist me in creating another key which is not the one specified by the actual documentation

Comment: The returned value is NOT ASCII. ASCII is the set of characters up to and including ~ (tilde). It may be extended ASCII or ISO-8859-1 or some other superset of ASCII. Be that as it may it is a string of characters that can be used as a key by the PHP encryption routines. You seem to be quoting the documentation out of context as well.

Comment: I have figured using the IV functions of mcrypt then using bin2hex, using this in the second param of the `pack` function seems to work without a fail.. BUT, my overall question is how to validate: `¼°K~:ØµGcï¼U«à)ýë®^A~/û*£` down to a specific datatype?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "datatype". We both agree that it is a string of characters and that it can be used as a key for encryption and decryption. You may be missing the understanding that if you perform `pack('H*',"bc")` you will get `¼` -- it is a byte value where `pack()` is the translating function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $key is the return value from pack, which in this case is a binary string (essentially raw binary values).  See the first line in the documentation for the *pack()* function return value: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

> Pack given arguments **into binary string** [*emphasis added*] according to *format*.

You would normally base64 encode a binary string before attempting any kind of output, because  by definition, a binary string may (and often does) include non-printable characters, or worse - terminal control/escape sequences which can hose up your screen.

Think of it like printing a raw Word or Excel file: you'll probably see recognizable values (although in this case occasional alpha-numerics), but lots of garbage too.

Base64 encoding is a technique to inspect these strings in a safe way.

But what your question implies is that you are very much entering this territory new. You should probably take a look at the Matasano crypto tutorial here: http://www.matasano.com/articles/crypto-challenges/. It is an excellent starting point, and completing exercise #1 in it (maybe 20 minutes of work) will shed complete light on your question above.

Comment: PakaK gave the right answer.  However, I'm unsure if the OP asked the question he intended.  Although he asked about the "datatype", I think he might be looking form something else... maybe a question about the format of the string?  Regardless, this is the right answer to the question that was actually asked.  To confirm that pack returns a string, see this codepad snippet: http://codepad.org/Ux7p5UI3

Comment: Whoops... misread the name, and too late to edit my comment.  I beg forgiveness!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question.. The only viable viable datatype this is submitted in is a string. As you said in your comment:

> I have figured using the IV functions of mcrypt then using bin2hex,
>   using this in the second param of the pack function seems to work
>   without a fail.. BUT, my overall question is how to validate:
>   ¼°K~:ØµGcï¼U«à)ýë®^A~/û*£ down to a specific datatype

You have answered how to create an acceptable format for the `pack('H*')` but as far as validation goes:

```
if (is_string($Var)){

}
```

Is the way to go, as this is how it's submitted. It's not a bool, hex, binary, int.. So the only valid method of validating is to validate it as a string.